# one-to-one complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the complex function $f(z)=\sin{z}$ is one-to-one in the domain $x$ belong to$\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and $y$ belong to$\left(-\infty,\infty\right)$
my answer is 
let $\sin{z_1}=\sin{z_2}$ then 
$z_1=z_2+2k\pi$ then $x_1=x_2+2k\pi$ but $x$ belong to $\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$
Does the solution work ?

Comment: I don't need surjectivity i just need injectivity because i need to show that the function is just one-to-one not onto

Comment: What's the definition of $\sin z$? $\frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2i}$?

Comment: yes it is so or we can use another form which is 
$$\sin{z}=\sin{x}\cosh{y}+i\cos{x}\sinh{y}$$

Comment: sorry you have missed i in the exponential 
$$sinz=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Your solution dose not work. Indeed,

> $$\sin z_1=sin z_2\Leftrightarrow z_1-z_2=2k\pi ~\text{or }~z_1+z_2=2k\pi +\pi(k\in \mathbb{Z}).$$

$\newcommand{\dj}{\Leftrightarrow } \newcommand{\yb}[1]{\frac{#1}{2}}$
Proof. \begin{align*}
& \quad ~\sin z_1=\sin z_2\\
& \dj e^{iz_1}-e^{-iz_1}=e^{iz_2}-e^{-iz_2}\\
& \dj (e^{i\yb{z_1-z_2}}-e^{-i\yb{z_1-z_2}})(e^{i\yb{z_1+z_2}}+e^{-i\yb{z_1+z_2}})=0\\
& \dj e^{i\yb{z_1-z_2}}=e^{-i\yb{z_1-z_2}} ~\text{or}~ e^{i\yb{z_1+z_2}}=-e^{-i\yb{z_1+z_2}}\\
& \dj e^{i(z_1-z_2)}=1 ~\text{or}~ e^{i(z_1+z_2)}=-1\\
& \dj z_1-z_2=2k\pi ~\text{or}~ z_1+z_2=2k\pi +\pi(k\in \mathbb{Z}).
\end{align*}

Then injectivity can be easily obtained by this.

Comment: may you explain how u got the equation in the third row? (the zero equation)

Comment: @HussienMohamed In real case, $\sin x-\sin y=2\sin\frac{x-y}{2}\cos \frac{x+y}{2}$, the third row is the generalised case in the complex field.